# normal curvature2

Tags: differential-geometry

Question:If the surface $S_1$ intersects the surface $S_2$ along the regular curve $C$, then the curvature $k$ of $C$ at $p \in C$ is given by

$k^2\sin^2\theta = \lambda^2_1 + \lambda^2_2 - 2\lambda_1\lambda_2 \cos \theta, $

where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the normal curvatures at $p$, along the tangent line to $C$, of $S_1$ and $S_2$, respectively, and $\theta$ is the angle made up by the normal vectors of $S_1$ and$S_2$ at $p$.

Ok I solved everything and I know I have the right answer just that I just want to be clearer about something. I have this:

We set $\lambda_1 = kN_1\cdot n$ , $\lambda_2 = kN_2\cdot n$ where $N_1$ and $N_2$ are the normal vectors of $S_1$ and $S_2$, and $n$ us the principal normal of $C$. We can observe that

$|\lambda_1 - \lambda_2| = |(n\cdot N_1k)N_2 - (n \cdot N_2k)N_1|$.

What makes it ok for me to have it set up where I have $N_2 -N_1$?

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be an exercise in linear algebra with absolutely *no* differential geometry. If you factor out the $k^2$ from both sides, what you want to prove is this:

Given three coplanar unit vectors, $N_1$, $N_2$, and $n$, with $N_1\cdot N_2 = \cos\theta$, let $\lambda_1 = n\cdot N_1$ and $\lambda_2 = n\cdot N_2$. Then 
$$\sin^2\theta = \lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2 - 2\lambda_1\lambda_2\cos\theta.$$

Here's the hint: Consider the matrix $P=\begin{bmatrix} N_1 & N_2 \end{bmatrix}$. (Without loss of generality, rotate coordinates on $\Bbb R^2$ so that $N_1 = (1,0)$.) Then $P^\top n = \lambda$ (where $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$). Now use matrix algebra to express the equation $\|n\|^2 =1 $ as $\lambda^\top P^{-1}(P^\top)^{-1} \lambda = 1$, and — presto — this is the desired equation.

Comment: The place the differential geometry enters is in realizing that $n$ is in the plane spanned by $N_1$ and $N_2$. Why?

**EDIT**: An alternative solution, probably more in keeping with the differential geometry course, is to consider the vectors $w_1=\lambda_2 N_1$ and $w_2=\lambda_1 N_2$. Using the [famous formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product) for the repeated cross product, consider
$$n\times (N_1\times N_2) = (n\cdot N_2)N_1 - (n\cdot N_1)N_2 = w_1-w_2.$$
Now take magnitudes of both sides.